# Trying to connect to host in Google Cloud Plataform

Tags: vpn, google-vpc

I need to connect to multiples IP's via GCP.

The range os IP's that I need to connect is 10.[0-255].68.[0-255] and 10.[0-255].71.[0-255]
But they are from an local network.

The problem is that my host in GCP is 10.128.0.25, so i think it's trying to connect to the range of IP's that I want, but from GCP locally.

How can I setup this?

It is like this:

**vpn-1-tunnel-1-route-3**

```
Description
  Rotas de filiais
Network
  default
Destination IP address range
  10.0.0.0/8
Priority
  100
Instance tags
  etl-filiais
Next hop
  vpn-1-tunnel-1
```

When I try to use *traceroute -n 10.111.68.18* i get this:

```
1 * * *
2 * * *
.
.
.
29 * * *
30 * * *
```

Comment: 1) You cannot connect to private IPs from the Internet. 2) You have overlapping networks which means this is unroutable. You need to modify one of the network CIDR blocks to be not overlap the other CIDR block. 3) You could assign public IPs to the devices in the GCP VPC and the connect via public IP addresses. 4) There are tricks that can be done with site-to-site VPNs to prioritize routes but this requires expert level skills and the right hardware/software.

Answer (score 0):

1. If IP address ranges for on-premise subnets overlap with IP addresses used by subnets in your VPC network, refer to [Order of routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/order-of-routes) to determine how routing conflicts are resolved.
2. On GCP config, Destination IP address range 10.0.0.0/8 is correct.
3. On Peer router, advertising next hop should be your Peer VPN gateway.

Please refer to [Interop guides by vendor](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/interop-guides) for configuration and [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview).